# Why BroadcastReceiver not unregister when service destroy?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i register my (Broadcast Receiver) in service and when my main activity close my service destroid but my (Broadcast Receiver) Receiver working good?

and my question is how way to keep (Broadcast Receiver) in background?

and my solution is good idea ?

myservice code:

```
public class MyService extends Service{ 

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Const.LOCATION_LOGGER_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceivers(), intentFilter);
return START_STICKY;

}

}
```

Comment: You can unregister it in `onDestroy()` of the service.

Answer (score 2):

When you create `BroadcastReceiver` in code (Activity or Service), `BroadcastReceiver` should be managed by activity or service itself.

Otherwise, if you declare `Broadcast Receiver` in manifest, if your application is not running, system automatically create new process for your receiver. This is extremely useful when your application doesn't available such as `BootCompleted`).

```
 <receiver android:name=".CustomReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_BROADCAST"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

onReceive   check service is running

Comment: my question is how way to keep (Broadcast Receiver) in background?

Comment: add this code to your manifest file. when your receiver get message . onReceive will run.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was correct. Add the code from there to Your manifest file,
then create new java class:

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//Do what you need to do when broadcast is received
}
}
```